# nested ui bootstrap modals, missing backdrop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

In my application I open two modals, one within the other. Both modals have the `backdrop: 'static'` property.

The first time I open both modals all is fine, but when I close them and then opens both again, the second modal will lose its backdrop, or atleast the background won't fade.

I will try and reproduce this problem in a plunkr, but I am new to those so I thought I'd see if this is a know issue, or if anyone has a qlue to what the problem can be, anyone?

**Update** Okay, so I created a [-plunker-](http://plnkr.co/edit/DUrBz37sLLtUhK4UA2wq?p=preview) with my problem, as I was creating this plunker I realized that the problem is with my `info` modal/factory.

I request some data from a server, this is simulated with a `setTimeout` function. While the data is being loaded, an information modal is displayed, this is closed before the first of the nested modals open, but I still think this one is the problem.

**To reproduce the problem:**

Press 'Open me!' to "load" the data, and open the first modal. Then press the 'hello' text to open the second modal.

**Note** that this is how it should be, both modals have the correct backdrop fade.

Close both modals and open them again, this time you'll see that the second modal has lost its backdrop.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you my friend

```js
        angular.module("app", []);
        angular.module("app").controller("ctrl", function ($scope) {
            $scope.openModals = function() {
                $("#myModal1").modal("show");
                $("#myModal2").modal("show");
            }

            $scope.openModal_1 = function () {
                $("#myModal1").modal("show");
            }
        });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

    <button ng-click="openModals()">open both modal</button>
    <button ng-click="openModal_1()">open modal 1 and then modal 2</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title 1</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">
                        Launch  modal 2
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title 2</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```